# Knockout JS building a list of items

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, mvvm, knockout.js

What I am trying to do is build up a list of items from some other larger list of available items (for context think a specifying the ingredients of a product of some type). I am still pretty green when it comes to Knockout and am wondering if I am missing something because the solution I am currently using feels wrong. I have a couple of pretty standard templates, and am using foreach binding against two observable arrays on my view model (one for the list of available ingredients and one for the list of selected ingredients for the product).

```
<div data-bind="template: {name:'ingredientTypeTemplate', foreach: ingredientTypes}"></div>

<div data-bind="template: {name:'selectedIngredientTypeTemplate', foreach: selectedIngredientTypes}"></div>

<script>

var productTypeViewModel = {

    ingredientTypes: ko.observableArray([]),
    selectedIngredientTypes: ko.observableArray([]),

    addIngredient: function () {
        productTypeViewModel.ingredientTypes.remove(this);
        productTypeViewModel.selectedIngredientTypes.push(this);
    },

    removeIngredient: function () {
        productTypeViewModel.selectedIngredientTypes.remove(this);
        productTypeViewModel.ingredientTypes.push(this);
    },
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("/IngredientType/Index")
            .success(function (data) {
                productTypeViewModel.ingredientTypes($.parseJSON(data));
            })
            .error(function () { alert("error"); });

    ko.applyBindings(productTypeViewModel);
});

</script>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="ingredientTypeTemplate">
    <div>
        <span>${Name}</span>
        <a href='#' data-bind="click: productTypeViewModel.addIngredient">Add</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Is this the best way to do what I am trying to do with Knockout? Something feels wrong although I'm not quite sure what. I did have a separate VM definition for ingredientType which had a add function on it. The ingredientTypes observable would be initialized with an array of VMs of this type, the template then just used data-bind"click: add" on it, but I didn't like having to communicate back to the main VM from this one that was handling the click.

Basically I'd just like an indication of whether what I have done is a standard approach or there is a better (more Knockout suited) way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is entirely valid and is what I've seen in other knockout examples. For example, from v1 of Ryan Niemeyer's [drag and drop plugin](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html) you can find the following code snippet which is very similar to what you are doing:

```
if (position >= 0) {
    originalParent.remove(item);
    newParent.splice(position, 0, item);
}
```